# Show the validation error below the input field

Tags: error-messages

REquired functionality:Show error message below the input text field

I have created a vf page where I am able to show the validation error when the text field is blank However inorder to do that I have to refresh the page. Once I enter some texts in the textfield it doesnt shows the error message .Then when I keep the textfield blank  ith shows the error message again when I write something in the text field the error message is still showing.I have to refresh the page again to make this functionality work.I want to make the functioanlity work without refreshing .I am pasting my code here.Please guide me in case my code is wrong.Thank you.

```html
<apex:page controller="Regpagedemo1ctrl" >
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="myblock">
        Email <apex:inputText value="{!email}" id="email"/><br/><br/>
        <div class="errorMsg"><strong></strong>&nbsp;{!emailError}</div>
        password <apex:inputText value="{!password}" id="password"/><br/><br/>
        <div class="errorMsg"><strong></strong>&nbsp;{!passwordError}</div>
        <apex:commandButton value="Click me!"  action="{!checkEmail}"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

```java
public with sharing class Regpagedemo1ctrl {
    public String emailError{get;set;}
    public String email{get;set;}
    public String passwordError{get;set;}
    public String password{get;set;}


    public PageReference checkEmail() {
        if(email.equals('')) {
            emailError ='ENTER EMAIL';
        }
        if(password.equals('')) {
         passwordError='ENTER PASSWORD';
        }
        return null;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use JQuery to do this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759308/required-field-validation-jquery-showing-error-message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below class :

```
public with sharing class Regpagedemo1ctrl {
    public String emailError{get;set;}
    public String email{get;set;}
    public String passwordError{get;set;}
    public String password{get;set;}
    public Boolean shwErrorMail{get;set;}
    public Boolean shwErrorPswd{get;set;}

    public Regpagedemo1ctrl(){
        shwErrorMail = False; 
        shwErrorPswd = False;   
    }

    public PageReference checkEmail() {
        shwErrorMail = False; 
        shwErrorPswd = False;
        if(email == ''){
            emailError ='ENTER EMAIL';
            shwErrorMail = True;
        }

        if(password == ''){
            passwordError = 'ENTER PASSWORD';
            shwErrorPswd = True;
        }        

        return null;
    }


}
```

Try to change the Page as below :

```
<apex:page controller="Regpagedemo1ctrl" >
<apex:form id="mnFrmId">
    <apex:pageBlock id="mnPgBlkId">
        <table id="TblId">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputText > Email Address: </apex:outputText>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:inputText id="myEmlId" value="{!email}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputText rendered="{!shwErrorMail}"> <span style="color:red;">{!emailError}</span></apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputText value="Password:  "/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:inputText id="myPswdId" value="{!password}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputText rendered="{!shwErrorPswd}"> <span style="color:red;">{!passwordError}</span></apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Click me!"  action="{!checkEmail}" reRender="mnFrmId"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

The above page will serve your need.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
    .error-occured {border-color:red;}
    <apex:inputText value="{!email}" id="email"/>
    <div class="errorMsg"><strong></strong</div>

   function validateField() {
    var isSuccess = true;
    var field = j$('[Id$=email]');
    var fieldValue = j$(field).val();
    if (fieldValue == '' || fieldValue == null) {
        j$(field).addClass('error-occured');
        j$('.errorMsg').text('Please fill in this field');
        isSuccess = false;
    }
    else {
         j$(field).removeClass('error-occured');

    }
    return isSuccess;
  }
```

call `validateField();` onclick of commandButton

Comment: Thanks d_k but the functionality is still not working properly

Comment: did you add the jQuery Library? you could still use what @Partha Sarathi Mandal suggested but it will become a heavy transaction when you'll reRender your table when your page/Table grows. JQuery is totally client side and I personally prefer using it for validation fields on page especially while doing a null check